# no included points Exception of google maps in ionic

Tags: cordova, google-maps, cordova-plugins, ionic3

When I add a polyline to my map, it gives the below error.

```
private routeOptions: PolylineOptions = {
        'points': [],
        'geodesic': false,      
        'color': '#488aff',  
        'width': 10,
    };

console.log("this console log is shown");
this.map.addPolyline(routeOptions).then((polyline) => { 
     console.log("this console log isn't shown as the addPolyline gives an exception");
});
```

It gives this error:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo.zza ()
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build ()
plugin.google.maps.PluginPolyline$1.run (PluginPolyline.java:79)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7325)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I suspect the problem has to do with the 'points' key in the routeOptions Object.

Any helps is appreciated.

Additional information: 
I'm using Ionic 3.5, using the cordova-plugin-googlemaps plugin (native ionic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Polyline API](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Polyline/README.md#add-a-polyline),

> The map.addPolyline() method takes a single polyline options object literal, specifying the initial properties of the polyline.
>
> points    Array.LatLng    The array of LatLng position.

Currently you are passing an empty array of points *which means no path is passed*.

The exception is also specifying the same.
You need to add an array of LatLng values here -> `points:[]` in `routeOptions`

Comment: Thanks Suraj, i guess so, although I'm making an app that constructs a path while walking, so I pass the gps coordinates into the polyline, so when I initiate it it is still empty. I changed the code so I start the polyline on the gps coordinate, it works now, thanks. If people are interested: I changed  'points': [new LatLng(35,139)], and it works now. Thanks Suraj

Comment: Updated answer to point to cordova plugin api and not javascript api